# RSelenium - Firefox SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Tags: r, firefox, web-scraping, rselenium

i'm trying to open this page in firefox using RSelenium and it throws me the error SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER.

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = TRUE,
               port=3490L, 
               browser=c("firefox"), 
               geckover = 'latest',
               check = TRUE
               )

remote_driver <- rD[["client"]] 
remote_driver$maxWindowSize()
remote_driver$setTimeout(type = "implicit", milliseconds = 100000)
remote_driver$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 100000)

remote_driver$navigate("https://www.farmaciasahumada.cl")
```

I added the server certificate error exception in firefox, and I still can't get into the site.
I saw that this problem can be skipped in python or java, but I have not found any solution for R.
With other browsers I have no problems.
I hope someone can help me:(

Answer (score 0):

I can load the page in firefox,

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver$client
remDr$navigate("https://www.farmaciasahumada.cl")
```

Try `chrome`, update your package and web browser.